# Create array out of data in collectioin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, collections

I have this collection

```
<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Fallower user_id: 1, author_id: 2, created_at: "2015-09-06 22:59:40", updated_at: "2015-09-06 22:59:40">, #<Fallower user_id: 1, author_id: 3, created_at: "2015-09-06 22:59:40", updated_at: "2015-09-06 22:59:40">]>
```

and I need to create an array/collection of only "authord_id" values.

What is the best approach how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@fallowers = Fallower.where(<something>)
@authord_ids = @fallowers.map(&:authord_id)
```

or

```
@authord_ids = Fallower.where(<something>).pluck(:authord_id)
```

Comment: I would also suggest you fix the Fallowed => Followed typo.

Comment: How do you know it's a typo?

Comment: Call it an educated guess.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [`collection#pluck(:author_id)`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)

Comment: I saw that #pluck have faster benchmark, but I forgot the link

Comment: `pluck` generate a sql query with `select (column) from table`, it's faster than load `all` records and `map` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Fallower.all.collect {|f| f.author_id}
```

or

```
Fallower.pluck :author_id
```

also, are you sure you mean `Fallower` and not `Follower`?

Comment: The solutions using pluck are much more efficient since you don't fetch the full record just to condense down a single column array.

Comment: @max true, thought about that after posting!